# Updating dependent stacks

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I have the stack called `stack-layer`, which exports an ARN of a Lambda layer, and another stack called `stack-lambda`, which contains a Lambda, which references that Lambda layer.

When I try to update `stack-layer`, I get an error: `Export layer-arn cannot be deleted as it is in use by stack-lambda`, which is totally understandable. However, I don't see how to proceed with an update from here.

Is there any way to update such dependent stacks? Amazon's [walkthrough](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/walkthrough-crossstackref.html) does not seem to touch this topic at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As described in [`Fn::ImportValue`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-importvalue.html) documentation, being unable to modify a referenced output is indeed expected behavior:

> #### Note
>
> The following restrictions apply to cross-stack references:
>
> [...]
>
> - You can't modify or remove an output value that is referenced by another stack.

In order to work around this when updating the output, you can use a second, temporary Output value to handle the transition:

1. Update `stack-layer` to add a second Output containing the new value (e.g., `layer-arn-2`);
2. Update `stack-lambda`, changing the `"Fn::ImportValue": "layer-arn"` reference to instead reference `layer-arn-2`.
3. Update `stack-layer` to remove the now-unused `layer-arn` Output.
   (Or alternately: update `stack-layer` to set `layer-arn` to the same value as `layer-arn-2`; update `stack-lambda` to reference `layer-arn`; then finally update `stack-layer` to remove the `layer-arn-2` Output.

It's a bit tedious, but it should work.

Comment: That is not an option when you have cloudfront that takes 30 minutes to update. This is terrible by AWS and they should make something to solve this bug

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/de/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudformation-stack-export-name-error/ Released a detailed explanation as well

Answer (score 5):

As the other answer suggested method looks a bit longer, here is what I did to overcome this problem after reading [this guide](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudformation-stack-export-name-error/):

1. I have updated importing stack (i.e. `stack-lambda`) to use actual value of exported parameter(I did that using AWS console so that I don't have to make change in my yml code, submit and deploy)
2. Deploy exporting stack (i.e. `stack-layer`) and make sure that the issue is gone
3. Deploy importing stack from code base.

This was done quite quickly w/o changing source code and interrupting service run.
Hope this will be useful, feel free to comment your questions.

Answer (score 0):

I found a built-in CDK method on `core.Stack` that handles this exact issue:

```
export_value()
```

Link to Python CDK docs here
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/python/aws_cdk.core/Stack.html?highlight=export_value#aws_cdk.core.Stack.export_value

> One of the uses for this method is to remove the relationship between two Stacks established by automatic cross-stack references. It will temporarily ensure that the CloudFormation Export still exists while you remove the reference from the consuming stack. After that, you can remove the resource and the manual export.

My example is needing to replace an old DB stack with a new one (changing from serverless to provisioned RDS).
I simply rename the old DB stack variable name and below it add the following:

```
self.export_value(old_cluster.cluster_identifier)
```

Within `export_value()` I pass in the exported output value that was causing the dependency issue. I can either hardcode it as a string or better yet can find where it is getting it from and reference that instead, in this case the value was from `cluster_identifier`.

After the stack has been updated I can remove the old DB cluster and this `export_value()` line.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use SSM to avoid importing or exporting in the stack

```yaml
## Importing resources created in other stacks
## using their SSM Parameter Keys
Parameters:
  MyEmptyBucket:
    Type: AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value<AWS::EC2::Image::Id>
    Default: my_app/s3/archive_bucket
    Description: The archive bucket created by the storage stack
  MainVPC:
    Description: VpcId of the Network Stack
    Type: 'AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value<String>'
    Default: '/app_network/plain/resources/ec2/vpc_id'
  PublicSubnetOne:
    Description: Public Subnet One of the Network Stack
    Type: 'AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value<String>'
    Default: '/app_network/plain/resources/ec2/public_subnet_1_id'

Resources:
  MyEC2SecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref MainVPC
```

Comment: Reference from https://tusharf5.com/posts/aws-cfn-with-ssm-parameters/